# Como obtener los minutos de un campo date

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando actualizar los registros de una base de datos Oracle SQL y no logro dar con la sentencia correcta.

La tabla GASTOS se compone de los siguientes campos:

**FECHA**

*TIPO: **DATE***

*REGISTRO EJEMPLO: **01/01/2018 12:00***

**GASTO**

*TIPO: **NUMBER***

*REGISTRO EJEMPLO: **100***

Lo que necesito hacer es ACTUALIZAR los campos que tengan los minutos = 00, es decir (12:00, 1:00, 2:00, etc...) por X (1 por ejemplo) valor numérico.

**Sentencia:**

```
UPDATE GASTOS
SET GASTO = 1 
WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA);
```

Había investigado sobre el tema y encontré que había que utlizar la sentencia TO_CHAR, pero siempre recibo un error, de sentencia inválida.

Un saludo, estoy a disposición de cualquier consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que estas pidiendo, solo tenes que agregar en el where la condición por la cual vas a filtrar los registros

```
UPDATE GASTOS
SET GASTO = 1 
WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA,'MI') = 0;
```

Como es un campo de tipo date, no se puede usar extract, asi que la solucion es parsearlo con to_char e igualar a los minutos que queres

Answer (score 0):

byte96 puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT to_char( sysdate, 'MI') 
FROM dual;

UPDATE GASTOS SET GASTO = (CASE WHEN '00' = (SELECT to_char( FECHA, 'MI') 
FROM gastos) THEN 1 END);
```

Debes especificar que quieres sacar de la fecha, pues la fecha es 01/01/2018 12:00 y to_char toma lo que le especifiques es decir

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') --tomaria el año mes y dia de la fecha
```

por favor revisa [aqui](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) diferentes formatos y mas a profundida

> to_char

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es necesario ejecutar la primera instruccion ? y otra consulta, el segundo FROM gastos a que se hace referencia ? a la tabla GASTOS o porque en minuscula ?

Comment: a la mismatabla, la primera consulta , el select es un ejemplo de como ver los datos especificos de una fecha. y el segundo from `(SELECT to_char( FECHA, 'MI') 
FROM gastos)` es una subconsulta a la tabla gastos

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar la función EXTRACT de Oracle:
Acá la documentación:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Básicamente para tu ejemplo se podría plantear el siguiente Query:

```
UPDATE GASTOS SET GASTO = 1
WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM FECHA) = 0;
```

Esto actualizaría todos los registros que tienen los minutos en 0.

Comment: Bien, y si le quisiera agregar otro WHERE ? por ejemplo, sólo los registros (Fechas) que correspondan al 01/08/2018, Cómo puedo anidar un WHERE a esa consulta ?

Comment: Extract no funciona con un campo de tipo date para sacar los minutos

Comment: @gbianchi tienes mucha razón, byte96 en el caso que tu campo sea DATE y no TIMESTAMP, la respuesta que te di queda descartada.
En cuanto a tu pregunta, el anidar una condición extra a tu sentencia tendrías que poner un AND u OR según sea el caso.